# IOError in imported python module

Tags: python, python-module

I have a module with the following folder structure

```
Module
-__init__.py
-analyzer.py
-lib/
-lib/models
-lib/data/
```

However when used from the parent directory I get an IOError for a file used in analyzer.py which is in lib/models. How can I get this fixed without copying the models and data to the parent directory

Comment: can you please post the exact error message you're having?

Comment: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/models/filter1'

Answer (score 1):

Every Python module must have own `__init__.py` file:

```
Module
-__init__.py
-analyzer.py
-lib/
-lib/__init__.py
-lib/models/
-lib/models/__init__.py
-lib/data/
-lib/data/__init__.py
```

The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages. In the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file.

See: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: What should be the content of each models file ?

Comment: `__init__.py`? can be empty.