# Unable to import a file

Tags: python

Here is my directory structure:

```
NEW3 has  2 sub directories:  
    NEW1    
    NEW2    

NEW1 - has test1.py    
NEW2 - has test2.py
```

How to import `test2.py` in `test1.py`?

Comment: You can easily find answer for this question in documentation in other topics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOError in imported python module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33801189/ioerror-in-imported-python-module)

Answer (score 0):

Add `NEW3` to python path, create empty `__init__.py` in each directory, then you can add this line in test1.py:

```
from NEWS3.NEWS2 import test2
```

To add a directory to python path you can simply add `export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/my/other/path"` in `.bashrc`.

There is a way to do it with python, create a file `mymodule.pth` in python `dist-packages` path  (`/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`) and add one line containing the directory to add to `python path`.

Answer (score -3):

Put a "**init**.py" file in the NEW2 DIR, an empty file is fine.
Then you can use "..".

```
import sys   
sys.path.append("..")
import NEW2.test2
```

Comment: C:\Users\29213\Desktop\TESTDIR\NEW3\NEW1>1.py
  File "C:\Users\29213\Desktop\TESTDIR\NEW3\NEW1\1.py", line 1
    import ../NEW2/test1
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I see, @sui-xudong, you totally new in python. Please stop answering if you are not sure. Your edited post syntactically correct, but gives very bad advice.